# Происхождение слова "катавасия"

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "катавасия"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это одно из церковных песнопений, сложное многоголосье. Видимо, из-за его сложности оно и стало нарицательным для обозначения неразберихи.